# How to compile header c++ filer properly

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header-files

I'm getting this error everytime i try to define a class on header's project file is there is any tips to avoid these errors ?

> everytime i run this code the debug respond with this message :unknown
>   type cout

here is the C++ (header.h file code) :

```
//
//  start.h
//  start_practice
//
//  Created by Macbook Pro on 11/22/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Macbook Pro. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef __start_practice__start__
#define __start_practice__start__

#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;


cout << "hello" ; <--- everytime i run this code the debug respond with this message :unknown type cout 

#endif /* defined(__start_practice__start__) */
```

Comment: uknown name type "cout"

Comment: and when i define class it tellms : uknown name class

Comment: You cannot have statements like these outside of a function body.

Comment: ahh thank you it solved the problem !

Answer (score 1):

**You need to put actions like `cout << "hello"` into a *function*.**

Things that are not declarations cannot float about in empty space. How would the computer know when you execute them?

So, in fact, the compiler assumes you *must* be trying to write a variable, type or function declaration. Because you're not, the resulting error message is admittedly a little confusing.

When you make your function, it does not matter whether you define it in a header or a source file (.cpp) though, for reasons I shan't go into here<sup>†</sup>, you generally want to do so in the latter.

<sub><sup>†</sup> In short, everything should generally be in a source file, except for function template definitions and `inline` functions that you really want to define in a header for some reason. Other functions will work okay too as long as you only include your header into a single translation unit.</sub>